# Do abilities that say "each player/opponent" target, and can I change who's affected?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an ability that affects all players is used, then does that make each player a target of the effect?

I.e. Is [Guttersnipe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGuttersnipe%5d) activated am I able to change the target of the ability?

Answer (score 14):

No, only things chosen for the word "target" are targets.

One notable exception is Aura enchantments, which are cast *targeting* the thing you want to enchant even though the word "target" does not appear on them (rule 303.4a).

Comment: If you look at the reminder text of some auras, the full rules text of an aura does use the word target. It is just for some reason they removed that reminder text from new core sets, you still see them in 8th edition auras.